# Which preposition to use in "lack of knowledge __ the manager"

Tags: prepositions

The preposition *by* is faulty in this sentence but I don't know which preposition I have to replace it with.

> The inaccurate planning is caused by the lack or insufficient presence
>   of relevant technical knowledge **by** the responsible software
>   manager.

Comment: The word ***faultive*** is hopelessly obsolete (OED's only citation for it is dated 1496). The phrasing of the example is absolutely awful, but it could be at least *slightly* improved by changing to *relevant technical knowledge **on the part of** the responsible software manager*.

Comment: . . . or *in* the responsible software manager. And get rid of "or insufficient presence"--"lack" has that covered already.

Comment: I'd rearrange it completely, to wit: "The inaccurate planning is caused by the responsible software manager's failure to possess the relevant technical knowledge."

Comment: . . . or "The planning erred because the software manager responsible for it had not mastered the relevant technical knowledge." Yay verbs! Get them doing more of the work and you wind up with fewer nouns to find prepositions for.

Comment: "The inadequate plan is a direct result of insufficient technical knowledge on the part of the responsible software manager."

Comment: @BrianDonovan "lack" means a total absence, it doesn't include "insufficient". In fact, it's the other way around, the lack of something is obviously insufficient (assuming some amount is required).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would write it "***on the part of*** the responsible software manager."

Answer (score 0):

I would write:
"The inaccurate planning is due to the responsible software manager's lack of relevant technical knowledge."